# How change this script to Blender 2.8, who is "use input() or raw_input() functions in blender scripting?"

Tags: python, scripting

I found such a script in this post
[Is there any way to use input() or raw_input() functions in blender scripting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109072/is-there-any-way-to-use-input-or-raw-input-functions-in-blender-scripting)

```
import bpy
import mathutils as math

# This class is the actual dialog that pops up to create the cube
class AddCubeDialogOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.add_cube_dialog"
    bl_label = "Add Cube"

    # Here you declare everything you want to show in the dialog 
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "Objects Name:", default = "Cube")
    scale = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(name = "Scale:", default = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) 

    # This is the method that is called when the ok button is pressed
    # which is what calls the AddCube() method 
    def execute(self, context):        
        AddCube(self.name, self.scale)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Added Cube")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    # This is called when the operator is called, this "shows" the dialog 
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

# This method adds a cube to the current scene and then applys scale and
# name to the cube  
def AddCube(name, scale):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add() 
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active.name = name
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active.scale = scale

# Registers the cube dialog to blender so that it can be called 
bpy.utils.register_class(AddCubeDialogOperator)

# Calls the menu when the script is ran
bpy.ops.object.add_cube_dialog('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

This scrpt was written for Blender 2.79. I think so. Under Blender 2.8x is running, there is a dialog box, there is possibility to choose scale, but When I press OK, I have such errors:

> line 16, in execute

```
AddCube(self.name, self.scale)
```

> line 29, in AddCube AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'active'

```
AddCube AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'active' Line 29 is:
```

bpy.context.scene.objects.active.name = name

What needs to be changed to make this scrypt work properly under Blender 2.8x

Answer (score 2):

**Scene.objects.active is no longer valid**

For 2.8 to get or set the active object use

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
```

however after an operator call the object has context, so with minimal changes

```
    def execute(self, context):        
        add_cube(context, self.name, self.scale)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Added Cube")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    # This is called when the operator is called, this "shows" the dialog 
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

# This method adds a cube to the current scene and then applys scale and
# name to the cube  
def add_cube(context, name, scale):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add() 
    cube = context.object
    cube.name = name
    cube.scale = scale
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a context in an operator you should use the context provided in the `execute` method, or else you risk encountering invalid context error.

Although this is not why you get an error in this case. Here you can simply use `context.active_object` since this will default to the newly created cube.

Replace your `execute` method with :

```
def execute(self, context):        
    AddCube(context, self.name, self.scale)
    self.report({'INFO'}, "Added Cube")
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

And your AddCube method with :

```
def AddCube(context, name, scale):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add() 
    context.active_object.name = name
    context.active_object.scale = scale
```